# Best beginner DSP book for developing plugins

Tags: audio, reference-request, books

I'm a computer science student and I love producing music and I really want to get into developing audio plugins. I'm currently learning the JUCE framework and am fairly comfortable with C++. I'm also good with maths.

I've been doing some research but I'm still not sure as to what book I should use to reference/learn digital signal processing. I've been looking at the DAFX book but its done in MATLAB not C++.

I need a book thats suited for beginners and for developing audio plugins. 
Any recommendations?

Comment: Will Pirkle has some good books.  you will probably have to learn some real DSP (which is more than protocols in plugs or in JUCE).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of books in addition to Zölzer's *DAFX*, the one I would recommend is:

*The Audio Programming Book* by Boulanger...

Also have a look at these:

*Designing Sound* by Farnell

*Designing Audio Effect Plug-Ins in C++* by Pirkle

*Designing Software Synthesizer Plug-Ins in C++* by Pirkle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've also come across this http://www.dspguide.com/ which is free and looks promising.

Comment: Yes that's also fine. You asked for best DSP books for audio *plug-in* development. Then you may also like *Understanding DSP*.